# Standard structure of Project in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I'm sorry to ask this here because I know it's not the standard place for a question like this, but the Azure forums keep redirecting me away from the actual forum to the portal so I've given up for now.

Question: Should I create all of my resources for a project in a "Directory" created when creating an Azure Active Directory B2C Tenant, or is that directory supposed to be empty except for the Tenant?

I'm coming from AWS where I'm used to the structure of infrastructure, so when there's essentially what seem to be new accounts being created when I create a service, it really throws me off.

I've attempted
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-create-tenant
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/billing#link-an-azure-ad-b2c-tenant-to-a-subscription

and all of that just creates new "Directories" instead of making the new Azure AD B2C Tenant in the "Directory" I am working in. Is that how it should be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure AD B2C is a seperate directory. If you want to create “container” directories, you just have to create a new AAD B2C directory. The links you followed are correct.

Comment: Ok that makes sense, I appreciate the confirmation